Managing multiple exclusive locks for a set of unique values
Consider I have a number of string values (dynamically generated), and a thread pool, and I want each string value to be exclusively owned by at most a single thread at any time. So, for instance, if the string "foo" is locked by a thread T1 at some period in time, all other threads waiting to process "foo" (or any other string equal to "foo" in terms of Object.equals()) must wait until thread T1 releases the lock.
So I want to implement the following interface:
interface Lock { 
    void lock(@NonNull String key); 

    void unlock(@NonNull String key); 
}

As I said, any thread entering the lock(String) method should wait (or wait interruptibly, or wait with a time-out) if the key is already locked by some other thread.
And the unlock(String) method should effectively unlock the key, throwing an exception in two cases:

Whenever attempting to unlock a key which is not locked
Whenever attempting to unlock a key which is locked by some other thread (not the current one).

Apparently, when implementing the above interface, I have to associate a ReentrantLock instance with any key that is about to get locked, for the whole time it remains locked.
How do I implement the LockByKey interface? Which concurrency primitives from the java.util.concurrent package are most suitable for this task?

If you already using ReentrantLock why not use it?

Is the problem the lock doesn't lock on an object? Maybe you could a concurrent map Map<String, ReentrantLock>?

@talexmovedtoCodidact Using ReentrantLock alone is not a solution. At least, I need to maintain a ConcurrentHashMap<String, ReentrantLock>. And I need to evict a mapping from that CHM whenever the last competing thread releases the corresponding key.

@matt exactly, that's the idea. Yet, I also want to reduce allocation, maintaining the atomic counter of competing threads along with each key, so that the same ReentrantLock instance (for a given key) can be reused by multiple threads.

Yes. You need Lock for each key and one more to rule them all.

Will a thread only hold one lock at a time?

You need something like this
public class StringLockImpl implements StringLock {
    private final Map<String, LockObject> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    @Override
    public void lock(String key) {
        acquire(key).lock();
    }

    @Override
    public void unlock(String key) {
        release(key).unlock();
    }

    private Lock acquire(String key) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            LockObject lockObject = map.computeIfAbsent(key, ignore -> new LockObject());
            lockObject.inc();
            return lockObject.getLock();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private Lock release(String key) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            LockObject lockObject = map.get(key);
            if (lockObject.dec()) {
                map.remove(key);
            }
            return lockObject.getLock();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private static class LockObject {
        private int counter;
        @Getter
        private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        public void inc() {
            counter++;
        }

        public boolean dec() {
            return --counter == 0;
        }
    }
}

If you search the net, you probably find existing implementation.

Your LockObject is a bit like a semaphore. You should probably make the counter volatile.

It only accessed under lock, so no need for special treatment.

@talexmovedtoCodidact, thank you for your answer! We can also switch HashMap for ConcurrentHashMap and get rid of one of the ReentrantLock instances (see my answer). Also note that both lock() and unlock() implementations are now using Map.compute() (as opposed to Map.computeIfAbsent()).

@Bass, Re, "switch HashMap for ConcurrentHashMap and get rid of [the lock field.]" Um,... IDK. You can use computeIfAbsent() when adding keys to the map, but you also said in a different comment, "I need to evict a mapping from that CHM whenever the last competing thread releases the corresponding key." How can you safely unlock the key-specific lock, *and* remove the key-specific lock from the map if nobody else is awaiting it *IF* you do not have a "master" lock to protect that sequence?

@SolomonSlow, thanks for your comment. Given that CHM.compute() is atomic, for any given key, only one compute() invocation may be running at a time (either that invoked from lock(), or the other one invoked from unlock()). So the counter field of LockObject, as well as inc() and dec(), are protected by invariants of CHM itself.

What's the special treatment? There is no synchronized when accessing or updating the counter, it should be volatile. Otherwise the updated value is not guaranteed to be seen across thread. It doesn't matter that there "is a lock"

ReentrantLock give "happens before" guaranty. It'll be fine.

The ReentrantLock doesn't provide a guaranty for everything that happens in your program. Odds are it won't make a difference...until it does. Your counter should be volatile so that the changes are guaranteed to be visible across all threads. Nothing else is providing that guarantee. The "special treatment" would be to not make it volatile.

Nop. "All Lock implementations must enforce the same memory synchronization semantics as provided by the built-in monitor lock, as described in Chapter 17 of The Java Language Specification:"

@talexmovedtoCodidact I am no expert here, but… I suspect matt is correct about counter needing to be either volatile or changed to final AtomicInteger/final AtomicLong for visibility, with Atomic… being my own preference. You are focused on the ReentrantLock, but the counter var exists outside and separate from the ReentrantLock. Your StringLockImpl.lock member protects access, but not visibility, as far as I can tell. But I may be wrong.

If you don't believe me you can read JavaDoc yourself. I gave you a quote from it.

@talexmovedtoCodidact Your quote doesn't guarantee that counter will be seen across threads. Unless it says something about that in the JLS from chapter 17. Which would have to be something along the lines of "anytime you hit a synchronized block, then every value in your program is guaranteed to be visible across threads" which I don't think exists. Either you have to do your changes in a synchronized block, or make the value volatile. Which is such a small change I don't understand the reluctance.

Read damn thing. Specifically "17.4.5. Happens-before Order".

"Either you have to do your changes in a synchronized block": what do you think "Same memory synchronization semantics as provided by the built-in monitor lock" means? Stop spreading misinformation about JMM.

I don't understand, if you can clarify I would be grateful. How am I spreading misinformation? I know that if you make changes withing a synchronized block you will be guaranteed to see those changes across threads, you will maintain "happens before" semantics. If you have a counter++ outside of the synchronized block, then it is not synchronized. There is no guarantee that the changes will be reflected across threads. Another thread could still use an old version of counter.

I re-read 17.4.5, what action causes changes on counter to maintain a happens before relationship and how is that relevant here?

@matt, counter gets incremented (or decremented) only inside inc() and dec(). It's private in this implementation, so no other threads except those entering inc() or dec() will ever see this counter. And inc() and dec() are always invoked with map-wide lock held, being mutually exclusive and maintaining the HB relationship.

@Bass That doesn't guarantee that the changes to counter will be reflected across threads. Yes, they will always be executing exclusively, the lock semantics are correct. The problem is similar to an infinite loop that waits for a condition to change, while(x){ //busy busy} if another thread changes x to false the loop doesn't have to stop because the jit is free to optimize away the look up. You need some sort of synchronization to guarantee the variable gets updated.

Don't see any reason to argue any longer. You apparently unable to read even what you wrote yourself.

@matt, you should read (or re-read) on the contract and the invariants ConcurrentHashMap maintains. Changes to the counter will be visible across those threads that read and/or modify the value. Whatever any other thread observes is irrelevant here, as counter is private anyway. Indeed, there's no reason to argue any longer.

@Bass what documentation has this " Changes to the counter will be visible across those threads that read and/or modify the value. " quote? If counter is volatile, that is true, since it is not volatile then there is no guarantee. Read chapter 17 from the jls and they literally have examples of values not being properly shared across threads.

Provided that ConcurrentHashMap.compute() is atomic, the accepted answer can be slightly improved using:
public final class StringLockImpl {
    private final Map<String, LockObject> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void lock(final String key) {
        acquire(key).lock();
    }

    public void unlock(final String key) {
        release(key);
    }

    private Lock acquire(final String key) {
        final LockObject lockObject = map.compute(key, (k, v) -> Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(v, LockObject::new).inc());
        return lockObject.lock;
    }

    private void release(final String key) {
        map.compute(key, (k, v) -> {
            if (v == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Not locked by any thread: " + k);
            }

            try {
                v.lock.unlock();
            } catch (final IllegalMonitorStateException imse) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Thread [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] not holding the lock: " + k, imse);
            }
            return v.dec() == 0 ? null : v;
        });
    }

    private static final class LockObject {
        private int counter = 0;
        private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        LockObject inc() {
            counter++;
            return this;
        }

        int dec() {
            final int threadCount = --counter;
            if (threadCount < 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Thread count is negative: " + threadCount);
            }
            return threadCount;
        }
    }
}


The answer doesn't share the problem with counter because you're updating the values inside of the comput method. In which case the ConcurrentHashMap documentation is relevant.
